# How to catch a change in UITextField text?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have looked at all the similar questions and they are different than from what I am asking. I need to catch a change in the actual text in the UITextField, not just the state of editing. It will be a first responder when the view loads, and I need to know when text is entered so that I can enable "Next" in the navigation bar. Please help me if you can it's really holding me back in my project.

Addition: I am currently using - it doesn't work:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, and respond to the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)replacementStr {
    // Enable "Next" if you like what's entered in the replacementStr
}
```

Comment: Do you mean UITextFieldDelegate? And thanks I'll go try it out.

Comment: @BenSender Yes, absolutely - that's the one, I just typed it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the developer documents for `UITextFieldDelegate`, specifically [this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)