# Knowing the complete changed string in textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I just asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604960/how-to-catch-a-change-in-uitextfield-text) about how to monitor changes to a `UITextField` and received this response :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)replacementStr {
    // Enable "Next" if you like what's entered in the replacementStr
}
```

This works, but the replacement string is not the whole string, just what it is adding. How can I get the whole string? My objective is to see if the string in the text field is blank or equal to a certain number (in different scenarios).

Please note that the outlet to the text field doesn't work in this case, because this method is being called before the text in the field changes.

Comment: textField.text is the whole string. At least it's the whole old string.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
NSString * proposedNewString = [[textField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:replacementString];
```

Answer (score 14):

**Swift Version**

In **Swift** We need to cast `textField's` text to `NSString`. The following can be useful:

```
let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString * searchStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

//    [textField2 setText:[textField1.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
    NSLog(@"%@",searchStr);
    return YES;
}
```